# Is it possible to create ASP.NET pages without the autogenerate javascript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

As a test, I wanted to have an ASP.NET page rendered without the auto-generated javascript.  Is this possible?

Comment: Which Javascript are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to ASP.NET UserControls, I would imagine that the javascript and css rendered with ASP.NET User Control is built in and cannot be prevented out the box. You may be able to override the render and prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are after to remove `__dopostback` and so on, you have to change the ASP.NET standard control behavior (like LinkButton). IMO, you can use ASP.NET MVC that gives you more controls on the markup.